# Maintaining MobileConnect Short Code Fees

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Once a short code has been provisioned and configured in MobileConnect (which obviously costs a fair bit of money), are there additional fees for maintaining that short code, such as a yearly license fee?

Any documentation I find references fees for maintaining short codes based on months/quarters/years, but not in the context of the Marketing Cloud - curious how this is managed.

Comment: Pricing can vary between orgs - best bet is to talk to your account rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is managed like any other service from Salesforce perspective, which means the billing is governed by the specifics of the product (if it's a long code or short code, which countries is it active in, what use cases were specified, what license the MC org has and what contract terms have been negotiated etc)

When you order a short or a long code, it is done through the official order form and over there you have the period this is applicable. If it's a price paid for 3 years (for an example) then during the next 3 years there are no additional bills related to it, you'll only need to keep your eye on SuperMessage count.